# how to monitor mouse pointer movement on the existing windows in Linux using Xlib

Tags: c, xlib

I am currently writing an application which requires to monitor mouse pointer movement on all the existing windows in Linux. I am using Ubuntu 11.10 with gnome.
What I need is to get the information on mouse pointer movement anywhere on the screen. 
Here is the existing code for doing the same :

```
void *MonitorOffline(void *threaddata)
{
    time_t      sTime, cTime;
    DISPLAY     *dsp = NULL;
    int         iError = 0;

    sTime = time(NULL);

    XSetErrorHandler(_invalid_window_handler);
    while (1) {
        XEvent event;
        cTime = time(NULL);
        if ((cTime - sTime) > OFFLINETIME) {
            log_msg("User %s is offline", cuserid(NULL));
            sTime = cTime;
        }
        iError = RegisterWinEvents(&dsp);
        if (iError) {
            log_quit("%s:%d : Error in RegisterWinEvents", __FUNCTION__,
                    __LINE__);
            break;
        }
        XNextEvent(dsp, &event);
        switch(event.type) {
            case KeyPress:
                printf("KeyPress Encountered\n");
                break;
                printf("KeyRelease Encountered\n");

                break;

            case ButtonPress:

                printf("ButtonPress Encountered\n");

                break;

            case ButtonRelease:

                printf("ButtonRelease Encountered\n");

                break;

            case MotionNotify:

                printf("MotionNotify Encountered\n");

                break;

            case EnterNotify:

                printf("EnterNotify Encountered\n");

                break;
            case LeaveNotify:

                printf("LeaveNotify Encountered\n");

                break;

        }
        XCloseDisplay (dsp);
        fflush(stdout);
    }
}

int RegisterWinEvents(DISPLAY   **dsp)
{
    Window window_id;
    char *win_name;
    int iError = 0;
    XSetWindowAttributes attr;
    XWindowAttributes wattr;
    Window root_return, parent_return;
    Window root;
    Window client;
    Window *children_return = NULL;
    unsigned int num_children = 0;
    Status status;
    int i;
    time_t t;

    iError = WDGetRoot(&root, dsp);

    if (iError == -1) {

        return -1;
    }
    status = XQueryTree (*dsp, root, &root_return,
            &parent_return, &children_return,
            &num_children);
    for(i = 0; i < num_children; i++)
    {
        attr.event_mask = KeyPressMask | KeyReleaseMask | ButtonPressMask |
            ButtonReleaseMask | EnterWindowMask |
            LeaveWindowMask | PointerMotionMask |
            Button1MotionMask |
            Button2MotionMask | Button3MotionMask |
            Button4MotionMask | Button5MotionMask |
            ButtonMotionMask | KeymapStateMask |
            ExposureMask | VisibilityChangeMask |
            StructureNotifyMask | /* ResizeRedirectMask | */
            SubstructureNotifyMask | SubstructureRedirectMask |
            FocusChangeMask | PropertyChangeMask |
            ColormapChangeMask;// | OwnerGrabButtonMask;

        status = XGetWindowAttributes(*dsp, children_return[i], &wattr);
        if (wattr.all_event_masks & ButtonPressMask)
            attr.event_mask &= ~ButtonPressMask;
        attr.event_mask &= ~SubstructureRedirectMask;
        XSelectInput(*dsp, children_return[i], attr.event_mask);
    }
    XFree(children_return);
    return 0;
}

WINDOW WDGetRootWindow(DISPLAY* pDisplay, INT iScreen)
{
    return RootWindow(pDisplay,iScreen);
}

int WDGetRoot(Window *root, DISPLAY **pDisplay)
{
    INT iScreen = 0;
    setlocale(LC_CTYPE, "");

    //Initialize the Display
    if((*pDisplay = WDOpenDisplay(NULL))) {
        //Get the sceen associated with Display
        iScreen = WDGetScreenOfDisplay(*pDisplay);
        //Once we have the screen , we need to get the rootwindow associated
        //with the screen so that we can traverse the window tree and get the
        //window with current focus (the active window)
        *root = WDGetRootWindow(*pDisplay, iScreen);
    } else {
        return -1;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

With the above code I am able to capture the mouse pointer movement on the title bar of all windows but am unable to capture any movement when the mouse pointer is inside the window (eg text part of an office writer etc) .
What more I have to add to the code for it to work to capture mouse movement across the entire window ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[XQueiryPointer](http://www.xfree86.org/4.4.0/XQueryPointer.3.html) claims to be able to return coordinates in the window.

> The XQueryPointer function returns ... the pointer coordinates
>   relative to the root window's origin.

Try that combined with your call to XQueryTree

Comment: Thanks a lot for the help.XQueiryPointer did solve my problem & I am able  to capture mouse movement across windows now. Thanks again.

Comment: One more thing I would like to have over here is to figure out whether the pointer movement is initiated by the user or by an automated script. Is there any way we could achieve the same ?